# typescript repo build fails on my machine but passes in ubuntu docker

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I have a typescript repo that fails to build on my machine with the error...

```
$ tsc --pretty -p tsconfig.json
../../../../../../node_modules/@types/graphql/subscription/subscribe.d.ts:17:12 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AsyncIterator'.

17 ): Promise<AsyncIterator<ExecutionResult> | ExecutionResult>;
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~


../../../../../../node_modules/@types/graphql/subscription/subscribe.d.ts:29:12 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AsyncIterable'.

29 ): Promise<AsyncIterable<any>>;
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~


error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I can't find any mention of `@types/graphql` when I grep through the `node_modules`. I do find `AsyncIterator` in the typescript module however...

when I run the build in a docker container in ubuntu, it passes ok, but on my local OSSierra machine I am getting this error. I have found fixes online that say to add "esnext" to the libs in `tsconfig.json`, and this does appear to work, but this repo is not under my control and I still have no explanation for why this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: If you had resolved this issue please share the fix here I am encountering the same error

Comment: My issue was cause by an errant node_modules dir that snuck into my home dir at some point. It was traversing upwards until it was found and it was full of junk. I deleted it and the problem was fixed

Comment: We have the same problem, but with a different error, 2 developer machines has around 20 TS2322, but I dont get them no matter what, neither does CI/the docker container

Answer (score 2):

We solved it by removing a rogue node_modules folder from a parent directory (in our case the home directory).

Apparantly typescript/node's module resolution looks in parent directories for more "information", maybe someone else has a better explanation :)